# Custom announcment board in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

First off, please bear with me.  My question concerns more specifically with custom lists, custom code inside Sharepoint 2007.  My experience is more with applications that work outside but access data (Client Object Model) in Sharepoint 2010.

At work I was recently tasked with the following request:

- Create a custom announcement board where everyone can create an announcement but only admins and creators can edit it.
- The main list page was going to provide a summary of the details, title and an icon that depicts the type of announcement (gif of a baby if birth announcement).
- Upon clicking on an announcement, a detailed page containing more detail of the announcement and up to 4 pictures will be displayed.
- When entering data the pictures can only be a maximum size.

Here is how I was going to attack this.  I was going to create a Custom List that allowed for the addition of Picture columns and all the other columns I required.  I would then modify the NewForm, EditForm and DispForm pages to meet our requirements.  Picture size would be controlled through Javascript of Jquery on the page.  My question to you experts out there is does this sound feasible? Is there a better way?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.bendsoft.com/downloads/sharepoint-web-parts/sharepoint-blog-reader/

Comment: Thank you Trikks.  I will take a look.  If my organization doesn't want 3rd party software like this installed what do you think of my idea above?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you are using sp2007 your options are quite limited. You can solve this by using the rest api but are up for quite a task. But your design with custom lists and so on is fine, thats proper sharepoint!

Comment: So just an update.  I had looked at doing it this way, but the user didn't like the method of adding a picture to a document library first, getting the path and then adding the picture that way.  So what I am going to do instead is create a custom aspx site that will upload details to an announcement list and will also write custom code that will allow a user to upload a picture, take that picture and save to a picture gallery and store the path in the list for viewing.  Seems fairly straightforward , I am a little concerned about coding the picture upload, but we will see. I

Comment: If you have any suggestions on the picture upload or sources of some code that could help I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you.

Comment: Use the fileupload control in asp.net, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx, there are some goodies in this blog http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2004/06/06/149673.aspx when uploading stuff to sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't edit the list forms - not in this case at least. One way you could build this would be as a publishing site. You can create custom page layouts to suit the design of the announcements. There would be a bit of work to build it into a polished solution. Depends on how far you want to go.